# How do I create a Blog mdel in django2.1, So that I don't need to use tags <p>,<h3>,<b> and all, Each time write blog I have to add html tags

Tags: python, html, django

I have to add html tags each time when I added the blog to my website.
I don't then it do not consider line change,heading and other things.
Model code

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE,related_name='blog')
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now= True)
    body = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    content = models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=0)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Admin Panel Html tag included[admin view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a47y9.png)
Published blog[Published blog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITgNp.png)

Without use of html tags[admin panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8acL.png).
Published blog [blog published](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VmHGh.png)

Plz let me know I it don't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a text editor on your TextField. There are a few you can choose from, like [TinyMCE](https://github.com/aljosa/django-tinymce) for example.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I added the TinyMCE in my code but it don't work for things like if we need to add github gists. If we have own build tag like "<code></code>" or specific "class=code" or tags then it won't work. For such purpose I find "ckeditor" work fine. [https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/installation.html]